# Multi-threading for read-only algorithm through Neo4j Procedure

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j

I have a big graph search algorithm which has implemented through Neo4j java API (Using as a Neo4j Procedure). I am trying to use threads (thread-pool) in order to improve the performance of the algorithm. The algorithm is totally a read-only but each thread needs to be a transaction in Neo4j to satisfy the ACID properties.

```
try (Transaction tx= db.beginTx()) {
            ......
            tx.success();
}
```

Since this is a transaction, I think a node can be accessed by a single thread at once.

- Is there a way to avoid this and access the same node by multiple
  threads at once because the algorithm performs read-only operations? (Otherwise, I cannot achieve significant performance
  improvement)

At the end of the execution, I have to collect all the results from threads and use `Stream<Object>` to retrieve search results. So, threads are not totally executed independently because a common data structure is needed to collect all thread results after the threads execution. To address that, I have used `Callable<Object>` interface. The problem with this approach is, it waits to all thread results sequentially. Some threads which start later can be finished the execution earlier compared to some other older threads. Since results are collected sequentially, already finished threads have to wait until get their chance.

Is there a way to overcome this issue or any alternate for `Callable` interface that we can collect results to a common data structure as soon as threads complete their work?

Comment: not sure if this is correct but the Session object has a readTransaction method that looks like something you can use.

Comment: FYI, if you read a node in a thread, you can also read it in an another thread. Locks are done only when you perform write operations.

Comment: FYI (2), the `readTransaction` is only used when you have a Neo4j cluster to helpa the driver to know on which node to redirect your transactions (a CORE for writes, a REPLICA for reads)

Comment: @logisima do you know how to call `readTransaction` using Neo4j java API?